# Custom SSL Pinning with OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

because of a security evaluation in the app I'm working on I have to use a library (made in-house where I work, can't modify it) for SSL-Pinning which has a function that receives a HttpsURLConnection object like this:

```
checkEstablished(HttpsUrlConnection connection)
```

This function checks if the certificate is valid according to a central repository with all of the server's certificates, etc.

I read about SSL pinning in OkHttp with CertificatePinner, but I need to implement this custom solution, is there a way to do it with okhttp (so I can use retrofit too) or my only option is to implement HttpsUrlConnection with no OkHttp for this to work?

Comment: Is there any example of how you implemented this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass HttpsURLConnection and override some methods to return data from the Response’s Handshake.  It's hacky and gross, but so is your requirement to use that library.

Comment: I didn't get how he could use okHttp following your response. :( Could you please elaborate this?

Comment: Create a custom implementation of HttpsURLConnection that delegates to OkHttp to handle whatever calls your checkEstablished() makes.

Comment: I think the purpose of this question is different from what I want. In my case, I want to use okhttp, but doing a custom certificate pinning implementation to not use OkHttpClient.Builder().certificatePinner(certificatePinner) in order to make it harder to be bypassed, like it is in this post https://blog.nviso.eu/2019/04/02/circumventing-ssl-pinning-in-obfuscated-apps-with-okhttp/